# Compare two dates with Oracle SQL if it's same date by only day and month

Tags: sql, oracle, date, compare

I have saved a date in my oracle db. (Pattern: dd.MM.yyyy) 
Now I have to check/compare by day and month, if today ss the same date or exactly 6 months after. But the year has to be ignored. For example. My date is 01.02.2001. Then it has to be "true" at the 01.02.2002.

Also I need to check if the date + 6 months is true. (halfyearly). (For example 01.02.2002 --> 01.08.2002)

I tried with sysdate, but I'm a noob in sql.

Comment: Is the datatype of your date really a date or a string?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do the comparison using `to_char()`:

```
where to_char(yourdate, 'MM-DD') = to_char(sysdate, 'MM-DD')
```

For six months:

```
where to_char(yourdate, 'MM-DD') = to_char(add_months(sysdate, 6), 'MM-DD')
```

Comment: do i have to change the date-pattern or can i leave it like in your example?

Comment: @c0dev . . . I don't know what you mean.  The `date` data type stores the date in an internal format that you don't have control over.  Assuming that your column is a `date`, then the above should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
substr(date1,5) =substr(date2,5)
```

this code compares first five characters of the data and checks if they are identical or not.